# Does Webm support cover art?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, opus

I am converting MP3 to Webm and the MP3 file includes a video stream for the cover art.

```
ffprobe filename.mp3
...
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 300x300, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

Using `ffmpeg` with `libopus` codec to convert the file causes a VP9 video stream that doesn't work well.  I noticed:

1. VLC Player doesn't show the duration and the progress scrubber doesn't move when playing.
2. Android Media Player doesn't show image for the cover art of the track.

```
ffprobe filename.webm
...
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'webm_bad/B01___01_Matthew_____ENGWEBN2DA.webm':
...
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 1), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 300x300, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

If I tried to use `-vcodec copy` option, then I get this error:

```
[webm @ 0x7fdddf028e00] Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

Does WebM support cover art? If so, how do I transfer the MP3 cover art over using ffmpeg (or other tool)?

Answer (score 4):

No, WebM does not support cover art.

From [the FAQ](https://www.webmproject.org/about/faq/#general-questions):

> The WebM file structure is based on the Matroska media container.

The cover art in a Matroska container is stored in an [attachment](https://www.matroska.org/technical/attachments.html):

> `Attachment Elements` can be used to store related cover art, [...]

A WebM container does not support [attachments](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/#attachment):

> #### Attachment
>
> | WebM Support | Element Name | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Unsupported | Attachments | Contain attached files. |
> | Unsupported | AttachedFile | An attached file. |
> | Unsupported | FileDescription | A human-friendly name for the attached file. |
> | Unsupported | FileName | Filename of the attached file. |
> | Unsupported | FileMimeType | MIME type of the file. |
> | Unsupported | FileData | The data of the file. |
> | Unsupported | FileUID | Unique ID representing the file, as random as possible. |
> | Unsupported | FileReferral | A binary value that a track/codec can refer to when the attachment is needed. |
> | Unsupported | FileUsedStartTime | DivX font extension |
> | Unsupported | FileUsedEndTime | DivX font extension |

Maybe you can consider using a different container. Opus audio streams, like the ones in a WebM container, are supported by other [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)#Containers):

> Opus was originally specified for encapsulation in [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) containers

If you still want to use WebM, an alternative would be to create a video stream with a still image along with an audio stream. The FFmpeg wiki covers that topic in the [Slideshow page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Addingaudio). Combining that with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677225/2738151), which explains how to extract the cover art of an MP3 file, you could do the following:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp3 -an -c:v copy cover.jpeg
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i cover.jpeg -i filename.mp3 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -shortest filename.webm
```

`64k` is the bitrate that you show in the output of ffprobe.

The encoding might be slow with the second command. The [Encode/Youtube page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube#BasicExamples) in the FFmpeg wiki shows an example command to create a video with an still image that uses the `-framerate 2` option, like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i cover.jpeg -i filename.mp3 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -shortest filename.webm
```

For some reason I do not know, the output video of that last command cannot be reproduced by my VLC and the player crashes. `6` was the minimum `-framerate` that did not crash my player, so be careful.

Comment: The command was meant for YouTube only. Many players don't like such a low frame rate.

Comment: `-map 0:v` is preferred over `-an` in the extraction of the cover.jpeg.

Comment: This process worked. I tried using AIMP and it didn't display the cover art in the player like it does with mp3. :-(

Comment: @hernán-alarcón, If I try to use .mka (or .mkv) as an alternative container (these are supported by Android), how would I copy the cover art from mp3 to the attachment on the Matroska container? I tried the looping video and it didn't work in .mkv (and was not included in .mka).

Comment: @chrish, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198604/2738151). It uses .mkv, but I guess it also works with .mka.