# Is it possible to add a custom thumbnail using ffmpeg to a .webm file

Tags: image, ffmpeg, thumbnails, video-processing, webm

I would like to know if there are any ways to add a custom thumbnail to a .webm file using FFmpeg.

I have tried the following commands using FFmpeg version : 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 (tried for both .png and .jpg images):

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.webm' -i 'thumbnail.jpg' -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic 'output.webm'
```

It results in an error:

```
[webm @ 0x557ada774f80] Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Seems like the above command only works for .mp4 files.

Are there any workarounds for .webm files?

Suggestions for achieving the same using other tools are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705833/does-webm-support-cover-art)